# Atualizar todas as Tabelas Dinâmicas ao selecionar uma Worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Preciso que todas as tabelas dinâmicas da minha planilha sejam atualizadas toda vez que seleciono uma de minhas worksheets que serve como dashboard. Usei o código mais lógico, mas acho que está faltando alguma coisa, já que a macro não roda, já que ele retorna "erro de compilação" para `PivotTables`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.PivotTables.RefreshTable

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente não é possível atribuir nenhuma ação a todas as pivot tables numa linha só, como se fossem um único objeto. Vc teria que fazer um loop para atualizá-las uma a uma, desse modo:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

'Dimensionar variáveis
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet

'Atualiza Pivot Tables uma a uma
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.RefreshTable
            Next pt
        Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado!